# Group Filter for taxonomy term in view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Right now I have it so that I grouped a list of taxonomy terms with Group Filters like this:

House Pet:

- Dog
- Cat

Sea Creatures:

- Whale
- Shark

All:

- Dog
- Cat
- Whale
- Shark

My current problem is that when using group filters I keep getting No Results, however if I use a single filter and choose one of the options I get results.

I have seen a lot of videos of people using groups with taxonomy, but I have not been able to replicate what each of them have done. I have tried using the Filter Criteria with the field as well as the content taxonomy has terms with depth option as well. The content is tagged and has departments (you can see it from the the field I am showing with the view) so I know that the tags exist, but they always return with no results.

Ideas, options, patches, questions, help? I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, try this.

1. Create a relationship to the taxonomy parent term.
2. Add a taxonomy term name field, add relationship to Parent.
3. Add another taxonomy term field.
4. Group by Parent term.

Hopefully that works out. You can also look into [Views Tree](https://drupal.org/project/views_tree), I've used it before and works pretty well for specific use cases.

Comment: It was actually a bug in the Drupal View module. I posted a bug in the Views Module and a co-worker of mine submitted a patch for it.

https://drupal.org/node/2049603

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a bug in the Drupal View module. I posted a bug in the Views Module and a co-worker of mine submitted a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/2049603) for it.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not bug, you can achieve it with below simple method

**Explain it with sample :**

I wanted to display a block using views where the taxonomy parent and child needed to displayed in separate fields.

Eg Books Parent term: Adult and Child Term: Fiction

So block view should be such that

Book Title – Parent Term – Child Term ie Eclipse – Adult – Fiction

To achieve this Go to Views

Add “Relationships”
Select “Taxonomy: Parent Term” (use the default settings)
Add Fields
Select “Taxonomy: Term”
Relationship: Parent
Add Fields
Again Select “Taxonomy Terms”
Relationship: Do not use a relationship

Now we have reached our goal … simple but takes some digging …

enjoy ;)

Comment: There's nothing here about Grouping. The fields don't group themselves :)